# What's the name of this part?

Tags: ford, parts, part-identification

I have a Ford Escape 2003 I'm trying to repair, and I'm looking for a specific part, but I don't know how it's named, therefore I can't buy it online. The part is this one:

[image: part]

It's kind of between the front left wheel and the door...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that it has a standard name.  I would call it a fender molding.  Per the parts diagram and description here (http://bit.ly/1wl5xii), it may be called a "lower molding without wheel opening molding".